# Chartjs v4.4 why can't I call myChart.Update()

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have read a bunch of solutions for swapping out datasets in chartjs but none seem to be for v4.4. Currently I have a chart, I want to click a button and change the dataset. I am able to see the change happening in my console but I can't seem to figure out how to get the chart to update. Any Ideas? I keep getting ".Udate is not a function"

***HTML***

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

***JS***

```
let currentSelection = DataArray;
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: NumberArr,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My Chart',
            data: currentSelection,
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: false
            },
            x: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    }
});

function myFunction() {
    if (ctx.dataset[0] == DataArray) {
        ctx.dataset[0] = NewDataArray
        console.log(ctx.dataset, "Part 1");
    } else {
        ctx.dataset[0] = DataArray;
        console.log(ctx.dataset, "Part 2");
    }
    ctx.update();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `update()` on canvas, but this `update()` is a method of chart not the canvas itself.

Modified js code;

```
let currentSelection = DataArray;
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
       labels: NumberArr,
       datasets: [{
           label: 'My Chart',
           data: currentSelection,
           borderWidth: 1
       }]
   },
   options: {
       scales: {
           y: {
               beginAtZero: false
           },
           x: {
               display: false
           }
       }
   }
});

function myFunction() {
   if (myChart.data.datasets[0].data == DataArray) {
       myChart.data.datasets[0].data = NewDataArray;
       console.log(myChart.data.datasets, "Part 1");
   } else {
       myChart.data.datasets[0].data = DataArray;
       console.log(myChart.data.datasets, "Part 2");
   }
   myChart.update();
}
```

You see here that I create a varible `myChart`. This use the instance of the chart which is created when you call `new Chart()`.
Then, this `myChart.data.datasets[0].data` is to access data in your dataset. Lastly, `myChart.update()`(obviously) is to update the chart.

Comment: Thank you! This finally makes sense to me!